# Confusion on RLDC Subreports

Tags: .net, reporting-services, reportviewer, rdlc

Is there a "for Dummies" guide to subreports? I am having a hell of a time trying to figure out how to get this working. All of the guides I have found seem to summarize how to set it up, but I can never get it quite working properly.

What I want to do is print a master record and all included child records. I have a view setup for both, but I can't figure out how to get this all setup to work together.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A Sub-Report is basically just a report inside of another report.

What you are trying to do sounds more like a DrillThrough report.

Take a look at [gotreportviewer](http://www.gotreportviewer.com/)'s website.  More specifically at the examples on the right hand side.  There are examples on both DrillThrough reports, and Sub-reports.  That should get you off on the right track.

Comment: Oh wow... how many other Got.... sites are there? I know about the two mail sites.

Answer (score 1):

The SQL Server 2005 Reporting Services Step by Step book is very good on explaining sub reports and drill downs and pretty much anything else you need to know about Reporting Services. Good for anyone from people brand new to SSRS and even those with experience who need a refresher.

Comment: It's good that you point this out.  I found it quite difficult to find some quality documentation on Report Services, quite specifically when running in local mode.  I have quite a handle on it now though, since I was forced to tinker with every available option.

Comment: Reporting Services is like the lonely stepchild of Microsoft technologies. If it weren't for the few good resources out there like this book, you would be wandering around in the wilderness looking for any help.